How to make Voronoi texture more regular
I'm trying to create a hammered metal surface and Voronoi does get pretty close but it is a bit too random imo. There's a lot of cells that are very small and elongated. Is there a way to make them a bit more regular and round in size?

To my understanding voronoi creates the cells from an original random distribution of points. So is there a way to affect the seed or average distance values of those points? I can't find any setting that seems to do that in the texture panel at least

Is this tutorial any help?

Well, the textures in the Texture panel are called "legacy textures" for years now so I'm pretty sure they don't get much love anymore. If you would create the displacement in the Shader Editor like shown in the tutorial which @JohnEason linked to, the Voronoi Texture there has a Randomness value to adjust this.

@JohnEason  I've seen that tutorial but I don't see the way to use that to make actual displacement on the geometry. I thought connecting the output to the Displacement slot would work but that doesn't seem to be how it works. And the Displacement modifier doesn't take materials as far as I can see so I don't see a way to use the nodes for this. If there's a way to do it then yea, that'd be great

@GordonBrinkmann as commented above

You can do displacement in the shader as well (before 4.2 only Cycles, nowadays in EEVEE too) Instead of a Bump node for the normals, use a Displacement node for the Displacement in the Material Output. More about how to do it in Cycles see this tutorial: How to use Material Displacements in Blender

@GordonBrinkmann Is this actually deforming the geometry? I intend to use it for 3D printing so I have to export it as an .STL that has the actual textured surface. From what I see in the tutorial it looks like something that happens in the render engine instead? Do I have to apply it in some way before exporting it?

Yes, it happens in the render engine. It is displaced geometry, not just an "optical illusion" like bump, but it cannot be applied to the mesh. Maybe you should give all information that is needed in your question if you want answers that work for you. You only mention texturing (in the tags as well), no word about STL export or 3D printing anywhere to be found.

@Cornivius I suggested that tutorial because you didn't mention exporting or wanting it for 3D printing in your question. Please be more specific in future!

@GordonBrinkmann well the question was really about modifying the texture. If it has to use a completely different system I guess that's a completely different question too
